# Create ManyToMany Relationship with self

Tags: java, mysql, annotations, many-to-many

Howsit,

I'm trying to create a `@ManyToMany` relationship within the following entity:

```
@Table
public class FormElement {

    @NotNull
    @Column
    private String label;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = FormElement.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "form_element")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "depends_on_form_element")}, uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "UK_FORMELEMENT_DEPENDECIES", columnNames = {"form_element", "depends_on_form_element"}))
    private Set<FormElement> dependencies = new HashSet<FormElement>();

}
```

What I want this relationship to say is that a FormElement can have many dependencies but at the same time is depended on my many FormElements (I dont need this data though). Now the when the table is generated in MySQL, the relationship is there, however unique key is not being applied.

What I mean is if the `form_element_dependencies` table contains these relationships (assume that the `form_element` table contains 3 Form Elements):

```
form_element | depends_on_form_element
--------------------------------------
2            | 1
3            | 2
```

then I change `3`'s dependencies to `1` aswell, SQL throws a `Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UK_7ya6hrxtosquk4vwmn0aefwyc'`.

How can I setup the `@ManyToMany` relationship so that the unique key applies?

**UPDATE**
Here is the Table that is being created. I can see the UNIQUE KEY is only being set to `depends_on_form_element`, why is this, should it be both columns as specified by the `uniqueConstraints`

```
CREATE TABLE `form_element_dependencies` (
  `form_element` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `depends_on_form_element` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`form_element`,`depends_on_form_element`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_s1g2g2d3bjcsv2j2lq143waki` (`depends_on_form_element`),
  KEY `FK_s1g2g2d3bjcsv2j2lq143waki` (`depends_on_form_element`),
  KEY `FK_osijq8sp1c5b8fskq8u4afk87` (`form_element`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_osijq8sp1c5b8fskq8u4afk87` FOREIGN KEY (`form_element`) REFERENCES `form_element` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_s1g2g2d3bjcsv2j2lq143waki` FOREIGN KEY (`depends_on_form_element`) REFERENCES `form_element` (`id`)
)
```

Thanks in advance, 
Grant

Comment: Paste your mysql create table sql

Comment: @Murali, Updated to include SQL Table

Comment: Why not create composite uniq key on (`depends_on_form_element`, `form_element`) and remove individual uniq key on `depends_on_form_element`?

Comment: @Murali, Thanks for your time, but Im afraid I've been wasting it :(. The error im getting is due to my own stupidity. I was restoring data to my Database after creating it, as well as restoring the table to a previous setup that wasnt working. So stupid. Thanks anyway.